# Using _binding!! makes NPE when I use binding after networking

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewbinding

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

I used View Binding at fragment as an official document.
After networking, This code caused NPE.

> private val binding get() = _binding!! (line:62)

I initialized _binding at onCreateView and I tried networking at onStart. And following codes are after networking.

```
 override fun getTimeSuccess(challengeTimeResponse: ChallengeTimeResponse) {
    when (challengeTimeResponse.code) {
        1000 -> {
            binding.timerStart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE //(line:256)
            ...} ... }}
```

This is my error logs.

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
   at com.alice.timer_at_home.src.timer.TimerFrag.getBinding(TimerFrag.kt:62)
   at com.alice.timer_at_home.src.timer.TimerFrag.getTimeSuccess(TimerFrag.kt:256)
   at com.alice.timer_at_home.src.timer.TimerService$getChallengeTime$1.onResponse(TimerService.kt:80)
   at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

This error doesn't always happen, but it happens sometimes. Why is this happening? What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: hey need more details  - please show binding mark up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the article, binding is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.

```
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

You mentioned that you call this code after networking. I suppose there are two possible reasons for NPE:

1. Network request finishes after fragment destruction. To solve this problem, you should cancel all requests in onDestroyView. Or in onStop to be symmetrical to onStart.
2. `getTimeSuccess` is called from a background thread. I can't verify that from the question description. But if it's the case, then _binding may be null sometimes because of [thread variables visibility](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/visibility-volatile.html). To solve this problem, you should switch work to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you! I am using retrofit for networking. So maybe the first reason you answered is causing NPE. I am trying to resolve this issue by wrapping it with if (_bindindind != null) {}. Is this a good way?

Comment: Wrapping asynchronous code with checks is okay. But additionally, I would recommend you cancel the network request when the fragment is destroyed. Canceling the request also will help with possible memory leaks. (https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a)

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you~

Comment: @alice You are welcome! You can mark the answer as accepted, so other people will see that the question is resolved. You may also increase the answer rating by rewarding me with ten extra points. But it's up to you ;)